# How to Set Default First Value in ComboBox inside the datagridview Windows Forms Application using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

My windows form application having Datagridview with combobox I need to set the first value for example ("Select item")

My result

[image: My result is.]

Expected Result

[image: Expected Result]

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmd_item =(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)(invoice_datagrid.Columns["cmb_gridItem"]);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT  item_name,sales_rate.item_id FROM sales_rate JOIN items ON sales_rate.item_id=items.item_id", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            cmd_item.DisplayMember = "item_name";
            cmd_item.ValueMember = "item_id";
            cmd_item.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Do you have a "select item" entry in the results from your query?

Comment: @Steve no i need to set initial value

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add an entry in your database for the *select item* text

```
....
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(dt);

// Add a fake record to the table with id = -1 to recognize it 
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r.ItemArray = new object[] {"select item", -1};

// Insert the new row in the first position of your table
dt.Rows.InsertAt(r, 0);
cmd_item.DisplayMember = "item_name";
cmd_item.ValueMember = "item_id";
cmd_item.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Now the value displayed by default in the combo for your rows depends on the value for that column in the datasource of your grid.
So, for example, if a row in your grid has the value -1 for the column where you have the ComboBox then the entry "select item" will be showed.

**EDIT**
It seems that you want a default value for your ComboBox column when you add a new record to the gridview. In this case [Microsoft suggest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/specify-default-values-for-new-rows-in-the-datagrid) to use the event **DefaultValuesNeeded**. In the event handler you can set the cell value to the desidered value to show the *select item* text.

```
private void invoice_datagrid_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Set the default value for the combobox column in new rows.
    e.Row.Cells("combobox_column_key").Value = -1
}
```

Here *combobox_column_key* should be replaced by the key for the column with the combobox

Comment: I got this error I put your code..The input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'

Comment: That's weird, you have two columns in the table returned by the query. Can you check with a debugger what columns are in the table _dt_ filled by the SqlDataAdapter?

Comment: sry steve now I got the result but I only choose the combo it shows select item

Comment: before I click combox it shows https://ibb.co/TKsBSbB
after I click  https://ibb.co/tmW52VW